# How to copy cells into another spreadsheet that changes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So, I want to copy some cells from a spreadsheet to another, but the problem is that the two spreadsheets change, they don't have a static ID. Basically, I have an empty version of a file, lets call it "example". Every week I need to create a copy of this file, and I rename it "example 1"; the next week I'll rename one "example 2" and so on. On the other hand, I have another file, lets call it "exercise", that function in the exact same way: every week I create a copy of "exercise" and rename it "exercise 1", "exercise 2" and so on. The two files always have the same numerical reference. So, I have to copy some cells from, lets say, "example 4" to "exercise 4", but I dont want to manually change the ID of the receiving file every week: I want to write a code that automatically searches the correct file (if we are in week 7, he should find "exercise 7"), and copy in that file the cells from the "example" file. I want this code to be executed from a button in the "example" file, so that, when I create a new "example" file and edit the cells I need to copy, I then press a button to copy these cells into the corrisponding "exercise" file.
I'm sorry if it's not clear... its a bit of a mess, but: any guesses on how to do this?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Do you really need to have seperate files, why not seperate sheets in the same file?  That way you only have to deal with 2 and once you know the id of those 2 you can add sheets and copy to your hearts content.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Templates

```
function copyTemplates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const tfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('Template Folder Id');//templates folder weekly file will be named with the name of the template + cid
  const wfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('Weekly File Folder Id');//weekly files folder
  const cid = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyw");
  let templates = tfldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);//only files of type spreadsheet
  while(templates.hasNext()) {
    let file = templates.next();
    let prefix = file.getName();
    let fi = file.makeCopy(String(prefix + cid), wfldr);
    if(!fi) {
      ui.alert('Error Creating: File: ${String(prefix + cid)}');
    }
  }
}
```